# Meteor: index.html is getting huge

Tags: templates, meteor

In my meteor project I can separate the javascript files in the `client` and `server` directories. But I cannot find a solution for all the html templates I need to define.

The problem I have now is that I need to embed this svg image in a template too, which is a huge image. So now I have this html file which is now 2 times 'huge' :)

The reason I need to have this svg inline in my html/template is because I need to style it with css. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Perhaps a boilerplate example would help:
https://github.com/SachaG/Void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the .html files anywhere! Besides the `server` directory, of course. The natural place to store them is the `client` folder, and a good practice is to keep each template in a separate file. The Javascript code related to that template (data helpers, events, callbacks) can then go to a file with the same name and with extension .js instead of .html. These are the basics if you want to keep your project tidy.